# Regex help for ##.#.##.##

Tags: regex

I'm not sure how to double digit regex numbers

This is what I have so far `[01-99]\.[0-4]\.[01-99]\.[01-99]`

The following should validate:

- 99.3.24.53
- 01.0.0.0
- 14.0.0.0
- 14.0.01.01
- 14.01.01.1

Any letter should not validate, no slashes either. Just numbers and periods in this specific format ##.#.##.##

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you want to allow `14.01.01.1` ?

Comment: That is fine, but only up to ##.04.##.##

Comment: `[01-99]` means match either the character `0`, any single character in the range `1-9`, or the character `9`. It will in any case match only 1 character. That's probably not what you're trying to do.

Comment: so in the second field it would be 04 or 4. Did you want to allow `00` in the second field?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Comment: You can use this to test it out quickly online; just a handy tool I've used across the years http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches all of your examples:

```
\d{2}\.0?[0-4]\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}
```

> I'm not sure how to double digit regex numbers

If you are ok with leading zeroes: `\d{1,2}`

If you are not ok with leading zeroes, it's a little more complicated: `^[1-9]\d$|^[1-9]$`.  The part before the pipe handles the numbers 10-99.  The part after the pipe handles the numbers 1-9.  A number like 0 or 04 will not match.

Comment: May i know why op specifies this `[01-99]` at the first?

Comment: @Avinash Raj, From the examples that the OP gives, the OP probably wanted to match all numbers from 0 to 99.  Apparently single digits may or may not have a leading zero.  I gave the Regex equivalent of this as `\d{1,2}`.

Comment: This is correct. I had no clue how to specify 01 or 1 to 99

Answer (score 0):

probe this

```
[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]?\.[0-9][0-9]?\.[0-9][0-9]?
```

So now it will match ##.#.##.## and ##.##.##.##

Comment: That doesn't match `14.01.01.1`